# how to fixboot and fixmbr on another drive

Tags: windows, boot

I have builtin SSD which I cannot detach before doing bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /fixmbr

So this commands result in fixing boot sector on builtin SSD not the drive i want.

How to change drive for  bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /fixmbr commands?

Comment: `bootsect` is what to use https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824948.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You cannot change drive for bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /fixmbr commands.

There is some Microsoft logic which determines the drive for fixing MBR, boot sectors and boot files.

You can use **bootsect.exe** for fixing MBR and boot sectors by specifying the exact drive.
bootsect fixes the specified drive boot sector and the MBR of the disk where the drive is placed.

```
bootsect /nt60 f: /mbr
```

writes a Windows 7/8/10 boot sector to drive f: and updates MBR code for booting Windows 7/8/10.

For fixing boot files you can use **bcdboot.exe**. It creates or fixes boot files on specified drive.

See for example "[Repair Windows BCD](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html)" for use of bcdboot command.